# using taos-jdbc to traverse resultset got " JNI ERROR (2355): JNI result set is NULLl"

Tags: jdbc, tdengine

I used an join query to require data from tdengine.The join query is like this.

```
select  signal1_0.ts ,signal1_0.c0,signal1_0.c1,signal1_0.c3,signal2_9.c4,signal2_9.c5,signal2_9.c6 from signal1_0,signal2_9 where signal1_0.ts = signal2_9.ts;
```

I executed this sql though tdengine's taos-jdbc connector,and the error trace is as follows:

```
java.sql.SQLException: JNI ERROR (2355): JNI result set is NULL
    at com.taosdata.jdbc.TSDBError.createSQLException(TSDBError.java:72)
    at com.taosdata.jdbc.TSDBError.createSQLException(TSDBError.java:56)
    at com.taosdata.jdbc.TSDBResultSet.next(TSDBResultSet.java:93)
    at com.taosdata.example.JDBCDemo.printResult(JDBCDemo.java:116)
    at com.taosdata.example.JDBCDemo.executeQuery(JDBCDemo.java:106)
    at com.taosdata.example.JDBCDemo.select(JDBCDemo.java:84)
    at com.taosdata.example.JDBCDemo.main(JDBCDemo.java:27)
```

this is a little strange, i can traverse the resultset return by queries like bellow.

```
select  count(*) from signal1_0,signal2_9 where signal1_0.ts = signal2_9.ts;
```

These are very similar sql, so tried to figure out what's wrong with that. I read taos-client's log file and this is error that I found in my taos-cleint log[image]

Is this error raised by the size of the resultset? since the join sql would return 3 million rows, and if i use the same query with 'limit' the traverse will be ok.  I want to ask whether my assumption correct and how can I to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the client of TDengine2.X will cache the query result set for 'shellActivityTimer' seconds. When the timer reaches shellActivityTimer seconds, the result set is automatically released. The resultSet.next()  returns an error.

Changing the 'shellActivityTimer' parameter to 120 on the client and server side circumvents this problem. If your application cannot complete the result set in 'shellActivityTimer' seconds, consider using LIMIT for paging queries